# Google street-view show directions trail

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is it still a feature to render road on google street view?

Most articles that mention it are form 2008-2009, so i assume they removed it in new maps?

Is there way to programmatically show directions blue line on street view panorama?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays), Polyline/Direction is not supported.

You can only add Markers, InfoWindows and custom OverlayView